# “initial” handling in flex&bison

Tags: bison

working initial.l

```
%{
 #include "initial.tab.h"
%}

%%
”initial” {return INITIAL;}
[()] {return yytext[0];}
.
%%
int yywrap(void)
{
 return(1);
}
```

working initial.y

```
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdarg.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define YYDEBUG 1
  char *filename;
  FILE *fp; 
%}
%token INITIAL

%%
initial:'(' INITIAL ')'
;
%%

main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv; 
{
extern   FILE*   yyin; 
if (argc >1 && !strcmp(argv[1],"-d"))
{
 yydebug =1;
 argc--;
 argv++;
}
 if(argc >1 )
  {
   if((yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
     {perror(argv[1]);
      exit(1);
     }
   filename=argv[1];
 }  
  else
   filename="(stdin)" ;

if(!yyparse())
  printf("Done!\n");
    else 
       printf("Fail!\n");

}
```

data file:(initial)

The two procedures are part of my procedure. Word “initial” is a keyword defined in initial.l, but it seems that it is also the keyword of flex itself. 
The way to express the “initial” part syntactic structure have been tested right.
The ouput: syntax error
           Fail!
Out put of my complete procedure :
     zhou:318.19-318.25:syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting CHANGE or STEADY or INITIAL

How to solve such problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use %token TOK_INITIAL "initial" means also made change in ”initial” {return TOK_INITIAL;} Then It will work fine.

Also Looking This.

**If you need to initialize something when your parser starts up, you can use %initial-action { some-code } to tell bison to copy some-code near the beginning of yyparse. The place where the code is copied comes after the standard initialization code, so you cannot usefully put variable declarations in the code. (They’ll be accepted, but they won’t be accessible in your actions.) If you need to define your own parse-time variables, you have to either use static globals or pass them as arguments via %parse-param.**

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `INITIAL` is defined (as a macro) by Flex, so do not use this name, just like `EOF` and other macros.

There is no need for your terminal symbol (`INITIAL`) to be exactly equal to its syntax (`"initial"`), so just rename it, for instance as `TOK_INITIAL`.  And if you want the error messages to be clearer (why would your user understand what `TOK_INITIAL` mean?), use this:

```
%token TOK_INITIAL "initial"
```

Comment: Actually, "initial" is a keyword of EDIF(Electronic Design Interchange Format), it has its own grammar, I can't chang anything. Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Really, I am not suggesting to change the syntax of the keyword, but the name which you use to manipulate it.  Roughly, I am not suggesting to change the value of π, but to use `PI` as name.